# cocoon in a deeply nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I would like to use cocoon with rails 4.0 in a project to implement a deeply nested form. I have a party model, which can be either associated with a person or an organization (not included here for simplicity so party just has its primary key).

Each party should be able to have multiple `postal_addresses`, `telecommunications_numbers` and `electronic_addresses`.

Each of these could be shared between multiple parties

Therefor:

`party` `has many communication_mechanisms :through => party_contact_mechanisms`

`party_contact_mechanism` `belongs_to party` and `belongs_to contact_mechanism`

`contact_mechanism` `has_many electronic_addresses`, `has_many telecommunications_numbers` and `has_many postal_addresses` (only electronic_addresses is included in this example and in the sample aplication.)

(Each instance of `contact_mechanism` should only have either a single `electronic_address`, `postal_address` or `telecommunications_number`. The `has_man`y relationship was chosen for testing and will be changed later once the nesting works.)

What I want to implement is a nested form, in which I can add multiple `contact_mechanisms` with as little clicks possible:

So preferably I would have an email link, a postal link and a phone link. So for email I would have a cocoon link to add a dynamic form for `electronic_addresses`, wrapped inside a form for `contact_mechanisms` wrapped in a form for `party_contact_mechanisms`. That way all relations would be setup automatically when submitting the form. When I use that setup (the Email button in parties#new), The following params_hash is submitted, failing to create an `electronic_address` linked to a `contact_mechanims`, linked to a `party_contact_mechanism`. The creation chain breaks at `party_contact_mechanims`, which get created with a `party_id` but without a `contact_mechanism_id`.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pyT1zgKlRBJgtBC/LGCNEaOcsPZxlmc5zEO3xd/THlg=", "party"=>{"party_contact_mechanisms_attributes"=>{"1373896051610"=>{"from_date(1i)"=>"2013", "from_date(2i)"=>"7", "from_date(3i)"=>"15", "thru_date(1i)"=>"2013", "thru_date(2i)"=>"7", "thru_date(3i)"=>"15", "contact_mechanisms"=>{"electronic_addresses"=>{"electronic_address_string"=>"juergen.helmers@gmail.com"}}}}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

It seems the instances of `contact_mechanism` and `electronic_address` do not get build and no values assigned. So I would need a way to insert a form for `party_contact_mechanism` and instantiate the nested `contact_mechanims` and `electronic_address` at the same time.

The second possibility to implement this form is following the cocoon wiki example for belongs_to relations (https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/A-guide-to-doing-nested-model-forms#the-look-up-or-create-belongs_to) and can be tested using the "PCM" button. With this approach one would click first to add a `party_contact_mechanism` form, then either select an existing `contact_mechanism` or click again to create a new `contact_mechanism`.

But the link for adding the nested form for `contact_mechanism` does not show.

I have a sample application on github for review:

[Sample application for this question](https://github.com/helmerj/cocoon_sample)

Any help on how to best implement this data model is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry didn't read all message, but first of all, as i know, that all nested attributes shoud have "_attributes" postfix in params hash which added by accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

On your `link_to_add_association` you could use the `wrap_object` option to build any additional association. If you use `fields_for` you need a new instance for each of those associations.

For instance, in your case if you want `contact_mechanism` to appear in the form you must call the helper like this:

```
# I'm using a helper because code looks messy in the view
def link_to_add_party_contact_mechanism(form)
  wrap_object = proc do |party_contact_mechanism|
    party_contact_mechanism.build_contact_mechanism
    party_contact_mechanism
  end

  link_to_add_association "Add...", form, :party_contact_mechanisms, wrap_object: wrap_object
end
```